# Right approach in doing this signup process

Tags: multisite, wp-signup

I have a client who wants me to have 3 steps when a user signs up on our wordpress site.

**On the first step..**
There will be a domain availability checker. If the domain is available, they will proceed on the second step.

**On the second step..**
There will be fields such as:

- "Email Address"
- "First Name"
- "Last Name"
- A Theme/Template selection

**Third Step..**

PayPal Integration. This will be the payment page.

---

As of now, I am developing this one with the use of these plugins:

- Pro Sites
- New Blog Templates

The only problem I have or shall I say a question in my mind is that.. what is the right approach in doing this signup process?

Should I edit the wp-signup.php? Can the wp-signup.php do those steps I mentioned above?  Is that too hard to do?

Should I download a plugin that would easily modify the wp-signup look? But would those plugin work correctly with these plugins: "Pro Sites" and "New Blog Templates"?

I'm not that good in Wordpress or shall I call myself a newbie, but I think Wordpress has a lot of hacks or I just don't know what i'm talking about.

If you could provide a code or what that will be greatly appreciated!

Thank You! :)

Comment: Never modify a core file and but never ask here for a plugin recomendation, it is off-topic. We can help you to code a solution if we see that you have tried to code first at your own.

Comment: @cybmeta Yes, I haven't modifed the core file, what I did was to create my own wp-signup.php file in my themes folder. I think that's a good start?